# Проблема с установокой gentoo

Tags: linux, установка, gentoo

Устанавливаю gentoo по [документации по быстрой установке](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gentoo-x86-quickinstall.xml).

На шаге `make modules_install` возникает ошибка:

> cp: cannot stat /usr/src/linux-3.10.17-gentoo/modules.order no such file or directory make: *** [modinst] Error 1

Чем она может быть вызвана?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте исходники

`emerge gentoo-sources && cd /usr/src/linux && make && make modules_install`

Comment: Возникает ошибкаmake: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/kernel.release'. Stop.ссылка на скриншотhttp://joxi.ru/Jet3Utg5CbBxLyhhPEA

Comment: запустил make menuconfigперед make && make modules_installпоявляется другая ошибкаusr/initramfs_data.S:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instructions setmake[1]: *** [usr/initramfs_data.o] Error: 1make: *** [usr] Error 2скринhttp://joxi.ru/Nu13Utg5CbBcMNAGSjc

Comment: 2скрин 404оя ошибка

Comment: при помощи `sys-kernel/genkernel` получается собрать?